# Node js - Node Path : How to find the Node Path on a windows machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, automated-tests

[image: vscode settings for extension Ponicode]

Hi,

Please see the attached picture for the settings of the extension Ponicode - used to automate unit tests

How do I find the Node Path for node js on my windows machine?

Node path for the test runner and tasks is required, and if absent node is looked up in PATH

However the default is not happening and I think I need to enter the Node path in the box myself

I have node V16.13 (LTS Support)
Node is working - I confirmed with using node to start a server on localhost as a test
I am not sure what "set the nodePath in your settings" means
I've uninstalled and re-installed Ponicode and rebooted my computer
I've contacted the Ponicode Team about this error too

Thanks,

Comment: Node will install itself to this directory on your Windows PC C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

Answer (score 0):

To find out where NodeJS is installed in MacOS you can type: `where node`

Comment: The question asks about Windows, but you answered for macOS. I tried 'where node' on macOS, but unfortunately it said, 'node not found.'